# What is word for a person who is very calm but also merciless?

Tags: single-word-requests

Those are my character traits but I want to explain my personality in one word.(only towards people who deserve it.Not to be cruel).

Comment: "cold blooded"?

Comment: "Hardtoplease" is one word. So is "*haveyoutriedlookingthisupinadictionary*"(?).

Comment: Of course I did but this is my last source.Besides I'm pretty sure I would get the better answer on this website

Comment: Technically, "psychopathic" might fit.

Comment: Cold-hearted? Steely?

Comment: @medica: So explain how one does a reverse lookup in a dictionary.

Comment: @jamesqf - They're called *synonyms*. And with dictionaries online now, it's really, really easy! One starts with "merciless" and goes on till they get the word with the proper connotation. Implication: the OP should try it sometime. You know, like before posting. It's called "research".

Comment: The problem is you may have already discarded all the terms suggested so far during your research before asking here, but how would we know? It's an act of courtesy to list which ones didn't fit, and say "why". It saves users time too. You say that your character is merciless but not cruel, which is a bit contradictory. Unless you consider a character such as Dexter to be admirable and just. He was merciless to those he considered "bad", but what he did was "bad" too. (I  have had arguments over this, so please don't defend the TV protagonist as some sort of hero!)

Comment: In any case, this question is begging for more context, the question may seem obvious to you, but to me, it is too broad, too vague, and primarily opinioned based. There are also two votes in favor of closing this question for **lack of research**, who could argue with them?

Answer (score 1):

calculating

> /ˈkalkjʊleɪtɪŋ/
>
> adjective
>
> acting in a scheming and ruthlessly determined way. "he was a coolly
> calculating, ruthless man"
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=calculating%20definition)

Comment: I'd appreciate explanations for the down-voting. That way I can improve my answer(s).

Comment: A single downvote is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @dwjohnston - I'm not actually worried. I genuinely wonder what the reason is. I thought my answer covered the bases pretty well. Thanks though.

Comment: Not sure....  I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Impassive = Not feeling or showing emotion, unperturbed, etc

You hint that such a person would be merciless only towards people who deserve it and not inclined to cruelty. This could be it. You may also find "indifferent" and "unconcerned" close, but they may not necessarily mean "merciless", though.

Answer (score 0):

heartless

> adjective
>
> displaying a complete lack of feeling or consideration. "heartless
>   thieves stole the pushchair of a two-year-old boy
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=heartless%20definition)

**Also**

ruthless

callous

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean *merciless*, then

*unremorseful
unfeeling
unsentimental*

But I wonder if you really mean such a strong word as *merciless.*  Maybe you mean

*coolheaded, unemotional, imperturbable, no-nonsense*

?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you intend to use this word to describe yourself, I think that ***[steely](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steely)*** fits the bill best as it is not derogatory.

> Coldly determined; hard.

Answer (score 0):

Relentless

Showing no signs of slackening or yielding in one's purpose ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/relentless).)